# Haskell function inside function signature type

Tags: haskell

I am struggling to understand function within function signature types in Haskell, 
I have seen this function;

```
twice :: (a -> a) -> a -> a
twice f x = f(f x)
```

Which does twice the chosen function on a parameter. I understand f is a function however do not understand why we have the signature type `(a -> a) -> a -> a`
I thought it would be `(a -> b) -> a -> b` because

1. You provide a as a parameter so the input of the function must accept the type of a.
2. b is the output type of the function so the overall output type is of type b.

I am new to Haskell :)

Comment: if it was `a -> b` you could not apply the function for a second time, because after the first time you will have type `b`, but your function only takes `a` as an input arg

Comment: Okay that makes sense so that's why it's all as for the type signatures

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's see what happens!

```
twice :: (a -> b) -> a -> b
twice f x = f (f x)
```

Just reading the type of `twice`, we immediately know:

```
f :: a -> b
x :: a
```

Therefore:

```
f x :: b
```

If `f :: a -> b` and `f x :: b`, what is the type of `f (f x)`? We do not know if `a = b`, so we do not know if we can apply `f x` to `f`. If we don't know then we cannot safely compile the program.

```
Couldn't match expected type `a' with actual type `b'
...
In the first argument of `f', namely `(f x)'
In the expression: f (f x)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are right, the function's type can also be written in the more general form `(a -> b) -> a -> b`. However, you get a slight problem with `f (f x)` then: the result of `f x` is `b`, but the outer `f` expects its argument to have type `a`. So `a` and `b` must actually be the same type! You could write this as

```
twice :: (a~b) => (a -> b) -> a -> b
```

where `a~b` is an *equality constraint* (you need one of the GHC extensions `TypeFamilies` or `GATDs` so this is accepted). But if both are the same type anyway, you might as well give them the same name right away... for example, `a`. This simplifies the signature to

```
twice :: (a -> a) -> a -> a
```